# Assistance in writing the rotational constraints of a spool, in rotational dynamics

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I came across a very interesting problem involving rotational dynamics, from the series of Cengage Physics books, which was asked in an Indian competitive exam called KVPY.

> Write the constraint relations of the spool, and both masses in this figure.
>
> Assume that the two strings of the spool have different tensions, and both masses as well as the spool are accelerating. Friction is sufficient to prevent slipping.

[image]

My attempt:

First, I drew all the forces acting on the 3 bodies. Since T1, and T2 produce anti-clockwise torque on the spool, $\alpha$ (angular acceleration) has to be clockwise. I have assumed $m_{1}$ to be accelerating downwards with $a_{1}$, and $m_{2}$ to be accelerating upwards with $a_{2}$, so the spool accelerates to the right with $A$.

[image]

We're aware that the acceleration of string having $T_{2}$ at the point of contact with the spool is a_{2} and similarly for the string having $T_{1}$, a_{1} is the acceleration of the string at the point of contact.

We're also aware of implementing the relation:

$$\vec{a_{poc,com}}+\vec{a_{com,g}}= \vec{a_{poc,g}}$$

Following this, I got 2 constraints:

$$R\alpha + A = a_{2}$$
$$A - r\alpha = a_{1}$$

But I struggle to find the third constraint. If someone could provide the third constraint and explain their logic behind it, it would be greatly appreciated.